# Suitable wire protocol for old house burglar alarm

Tags: wire, can

My house and outbuildings have a simple 20 year old burglar alarm with magnetic open/closed, shock sensors and a few PIRs.

The main control panel has failed so I was looking to modernise the alarm system and hook it up to the [Hassio Home Assistant.](https://www.home-assistant.io/hassio/)

I had hoped to use the existing cabling, new sensors and an ESP32 in each main window/door/area.  The ESP32 would be connected to each sensor and would signal an event using CAN (SN65HVD230 CAN Bus Transceiver) over existing cabling.  This would allow me to see exactly what windows or doors are open which is something the old system could not do.

Some potential problems however:

- The cabling is effectively a star network and CAN is designed to work
  on a bus
- The current system is multi-zone and cables are buried behind walls/underground. CAN requires a
  termination resistor at each end of a cable

Total cable length is about 120M and the cables are 4 core.

Might CAN work on a lower speed with this topology, or is there another on the wire protocol I should use? I also considered using existing wiring for power alone and ESP-MESH for communication but that looks even more complicated.

Comment: You'll probably get away with slow speed RS485 interfaces. You can probably make a system that uses phantom power but now it's more likely you'll need to send and receive using a carrier frequency to keep the signalling distant from the DC.

Comment: You can probably get away with CAN as well, but keep the baudrate as low as possible (10kbps preferred) and add the two 120R resistors somewhere furthest away from the middle. It's not at all professional to have such long stubs, but it might work in practice, since CAN is so rugged. Only way to find out is to try it. Connect some 3-4 nodes together with cables and keep one in the middle, then toss in 120R at the end of the longest stubs. If you can keep traffic running for some hour without getting any error frames, it should be OK.

Comment: If that's too much of a dirty hack, then you'll have to use some manner of gateway repeaters in the middle, so that each wire forms a point to point CAN bus, the repeater bridging over to another bus in the middle. Expensive solution but much more professional and rugged - and you can safely use any baudrate.